# How to change the included CSS files on button click?

Tags: asp.net, css

I would like to implement the application where user can include the different CSS files when clicked on different buttons. Please let me know how this can be achieved. I don't want to use the theme feature.

I am trying to change the CSS but I have noticed the ungly behaviour as follows:

1. When using mozilla i see the source
   code for page i see code for latest
   CSS.
2. But its not getting downloaded/ tried using the tamper data request to download CSS is not getting sent.
3. When I inspect the elements style is still the old file

Any idea what could be causing this? Please let me know how to get this working. Desperately looking for a solution.

Can this be done nicely using the ScriptManager control ?

Comment: You say you're trying to change the CSS, but you don't say how.  Can you explain what you're trying?  Why don't you want to use the pre-written functionality?

Comment: I want to offer user facility on the UI where he can choose say for example background of the top navigator, color, links color etc. So simple solution i found is read styles user selected and write it wo say customer_css_1.css and include it in the end of head section of page to override the default styles.

Answer (score 0):

To change styles on the client-side, you need to programmably change the  reference to the stylesheet, which would work.  However, you wouldn't see this changed in the view source... view source isn't a running document, inspecting all the changes made by JavaScript... so that can be a pain.

Firebug is pretty good, but again, even with Firefox/FireBug, IE dev tools, certain things don't get updated, depending on what you are doing.

So did you write some code and you are not seeing the changes directly, or you see the changes but you can't verify them?

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use **xmlHttpRequest** with **GET** verb in order to obtain the needed CSS file from a dedicated handler. Pass the name of the style sheet that you need to request as a query string argument. I suggest that you fire the request dynamically, on click of the button who should download the respective CSS file.